# echo part of WP get_comments() array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

having trouble echoing the part of the array i want (using `get_comments()` WordPress function). I've been reading about it but can seem to get it to work:

```
$args = array(
'meta_value'   => 'tagline111'
);

echo get_comments($args[comment_content][0]);
```

but I just get: `"Array"`

I've tried every which way: placing the `[]` inside the parenthesis and outside placing quotes around, using double parenthesis...

when i `print_r(get_comments($args));` i have:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [comment_ID] => 8 [comment_post_ID] => 367
[comment_author] => pppaul [comment_author_email] => af@gmail.com [comment_author_url]
=> [comment_author_IP] => 127.0.0.1 [comment_date] => 2014-07-13 06:41:11 
[comment_date_gmt] => 2014-07-13 06:41:11 [comment_content] => some content 
[comment_karma] => 0 [comment_approved] => 1 [comment_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0 [comment_type] => [comment_parent] 
=> 0 [user_id] => 1 [meta_id] => 28 [comment_id] => 8 [meta_key] => referance2  
[meta_value] => tagline111 ) )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since the result is object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_value' => 'tagline111'
);

$comments = get_comments( $args );

foreach( $comments as $comment ) :
    // echo something
endforeach;
```

Comment: I know this is entry level stuff but...if i want to echo the [comment_content] values what do i echo inside the loop?

Comment: `$comment` is an object so you can echo the comment content like this: `echo $comment->comment_content;` See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments#Returns) for a list of object properties that you can echo.